# Plugin.php not found

Tags: errors

Hi guys i recently encountered a issue with our wordpress site, whenever we try to go to updates or plugin page the website says page not found.[image]

error log :

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home/manhatta3/public_html/bluehawktactical.co.za/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php on line 2734

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home/manhatta3/public_html/bluehawktactical.co.za/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php on line 2738

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home/manhatta3/public_html/bluehawktactical.co.za/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/output.class.php on line 3679

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /home/manhatta3/public_html/bluehawktactical.co.za/wp-content/plugins/templatation-framework/inc/redux/redux-framework/inc/class.redux_filesystem.php on line 29

Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /home/manhatta3/public_html/bluehawktactical.co.za/wp-content/plugins/wp-leads-builder-any-crm/templates/SmackContactFormGenerator.php on line 11

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/manhatta3/public_html/bluehawktactical.co.za/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php:2734) in /home/manhatta3/public_html/bluehawktactical.co.za/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6712

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/manhatta3/public_html/bluehawktactical.co.za/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php:2734) in /home/manhatta3/public_html/bluehawktactical.co.za/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1310

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/manhatta3/public_html/bluehawktactical.co.za/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php:2734) in /home/manhatta3/public_html/bluehawktactical.co.za/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 9

Comment: It should be plugins plural, /wp-admin/plugins.php ? This is provided by WordPress core so if it's missing then something is wrong with your install.

Comment: The error logs look like problems with your plugins: revslider, templatation-framework and wp-leads-builder-any-crm. If you've got the latest versions of those then I'd ask the plugin authors about fixing them. But they're just warnings and shouldn't break your plugins page.

Comment: It's also possible that Bluehawk have customised the dashboard, so I'd ask them too if you haven't already.

Comment: It does with all the dashboard pages, settings, updates etc

Comment: Does what - log those warnings? I don't think that's the main problem here.

Comment: Have you tried to disable all plugins and enable them one by one? Have you tried to switch to a default theme?